# Rails 4 simple_form collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How do I translate the following to simple form?

```
<%= form_for(@bill) do |f| %>

<%= f.label :location_id %>
<%= f.collection_select(:location_id, @locations, :id, :location_name, 
      {:selected => @bill.location_id}) %>
```

I can't use a simple association because @locations is the result of a where query.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= simple_form_for @bill do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :location,:collection => @locations,:label_method => :location_name,:value_method => :id,:label => "Location" ,:include_blank => false %>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
<%end%>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Works after I delete the extra "collection:", except that it adds a blank which I don't want.

Comment: @markhorrocks There is an options called `include_blank => false` just add it

Comment: @markhorrocks Edited the answer with `include_blank => false` options

Answer (score 7):

Here is the final:

```
<%= f.input :location_id, collection: @locations, label_method: :location_name, value_method: :id,label: "Location", include_blank: false, selected: @bill.location_id %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In simple form, if we have an association between location and bill, than we can do like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @bill do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :location, collection: @locations, priority: @bill.location %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: There is such an association but @locations = Location.where(club_id: club_id), however, that looks like it may still work?

Comment: If you dont have a proper association than:
<%= f.input :location, collection: @locations %>

Comment: The association is defined in both the models but it produced some kind of hash for Location without an error. The rails form helper works fine.

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I was looking for. A way to have a custom collection but still send the nested fields for the association in the correct format.

Answer (score -1):

In your location model, you can also create a :

```
def to_label
  location_name
end
```

Comment: `to_label` is a view/display responsibility and shouldn't be defined in your model (which should only have business logic and DB concerns).