# rails form_for and object name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had a doubt with the following code here and i saw this code in the link here . [Rails 4 simple_form collection_select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702426/rails-4-simple-form-collection-select) ..

```
<%= simple_form_for @bill do |f| %>
<%= f.input :location,:collection => @locations,:label_method => :location_name,:value_method => :id,:label => "Location" ,:include_blank => false %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<%end%>
```

What does the `@bill` mean ? Is that a **model** name that we create in rails or is that a **controller** name ? Because both model and controller has a class. so it `@bill` can be the object of either of the classes. When used the command:

```
 "rails g scaffold bill"
```

It creates view, model and controller with the same name... thanks in advance

Comment: @bill is a model class instance

Comment: @AlokAnand .. oh. so to use the model class variables we are creating an instance of it. but can we declare a model class with some variables and assign it with a value so that the values can be displayed in the view. i mean without using or connecting to a db.

Comment: yes, for new form it will have new object and for edit form it will contain attributes' values.

Comment: Oh .. thats really clear and pakka .. thank you . @AlokAnand