# Label option for collection_select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, rails-i18n

I have applied localization for a select box label as follows. Label option not working in collection_select in rails form. How can I change the code to get the label

**Updated**

```
 = simple_form_for @product do |f|
  = error_notification f
  .form-inputs
    .row
      .span5
        = f.input :name, :input_html => {:maxlength => 100}
      .span5
        - unless @product.company.nil?
          = f.input :company_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @product.company.id}
        - else
          = f.association :company, :prompt => "Select Company"
    .row
      .span10
        %div#product_existence_message
        - unless @product.company.nil?
          = f.collection_select :product_type_id, ProductType.all,:id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select Product Type', :label => :label => t('forms.products.label.name'), :selected =>@product.product_type_id }
```

Comment: your syntax is correct. It should have shown the label.

Comment: Can we see your en.yml file? Or any other file you have defined this locale?

Comment: is it ignoring the label you have specified (and showing default value), or not showing anything at all?

Comment: @kiddorails - not showing anything. is there any other way to do it. If I add any label above to the select box, it shows translation error. Missing (Translation ID: 2716304)

Comment: Do `:label => "Sample Label"` and check if label is then showing this value. This will verify that your views are setup correctly to show label and the problem is in translations at `en.yml`.

Comment: @kiddorails - Hard coding like above not working, shows nothing

Comment: First of all just to make sure you have locale defined correctly I would try rendering just `= t('forms.products.label.name')` and make sure you are doing this on `.slim` or `.haml` file not `erb`.

Comment: @dahal - i am running this in a haml file only

Comment: @kiddorails - Yes it ignores the label. Select box only shown

Comment: @Jefferson can you post the code for your entire form?

Comment: Try running this on your rails console `I18n.t('forms.products.label.name')`, see if this gives you any error?

Comment: @dahal problem is likely not with translation, but rather with how view/form is configured. If hardcoding the label value didn't work, no value of transaltion will show in view in that case.

Comment: I have seen this problem when I was using bootstrap form with rails and had setup the `label_col` to `col-sm-0` (which is basically saying giving no space to label column)

Comment: I am getting the value in console while running  I18n.t('forms.products.label.name')

Comment: @kiddorails - Updated my post with the codes

Comment: @Jefferson: long shot, but try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17744727/1376448

Answer (score 0):

File: en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      product:
        product_type: 'Product Type translation here'
```

File: template.html.erb

```
<%= label(:product, product_type) %>
# => <label for="product_product_type">Product Type translation here</label>
```

Reference: [https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label[https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label]](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label%5Bhttps://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label%5D)